# Guess the number C# game

Tags: c#

I need to write a 'guess the number' program including numbers between 1-100 including a While Loop. It also needs to tell the user how many guesses they've had at the end and I frankly have no idea how to do that. Also, the user has to type their guess 3 times before the program responds and tells them whether it's higher or lower than the random number.
Here's my code:

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
int x = RandomClass.Next(1, 100);
Console.WriteLine("I am thinking of a number between 1-100. Can you guess what it is?");
int guess = 0;
while (guess != x)
{
  guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // ReadLine 1
  if (guess == x)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Well done! The answer was " + x + " and you found it in XXXX guesses");
    Console.ReadLine(); // ReadLine 2
  }
  else if (guess != x)
  {
    if (guess < x)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("No, the number I am thinking of is higher than " + guess + ". Can you guess what it is?");
      Console.ReadLine(); // ReadLine 3
    }
    else if (guess > x)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("No, the number I am thinking of is lower than " + guess + ". Can you guess what it is?");
      Console.ReadLine(); // ReadLine 4
    }
  }
  Console.ReadLine(); // ReadLine 5.
}
```

And here's what it looks like when I debug:

```
I am thinking of a number between 1-100. Can you guess what it is?
50
50
50
No, the number I am thinking of is lower than 50. Can you guess what it is? 
40
40
40
No, the number I am thinking of is higher than 40. Can you guess what it is?
45
45
45
```

and so on.

Comment: Well, you have `Console.ReadLine()`four times, you only need it once. No offense, but this question is really too basic for Stack Overflow. You're only missing a counter...

Comment: I'm not sure why you have not tried to debug your code to see where all multiple request for input come from. If you are not using Visual Studio consider installing one (i.e. [Visual Studio Express for Desktop](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) ) and debug code there - you should see as @Kobi suggested that when you "Step Over" each line it waits for input multiple times in same iteration.

Comment: @Kobi i removed all of the `Console.ReadLine()` except for the one at the top but i still have to enter my guess twice before the program responds. also, whats a counter?

Comment: In your editor, find the text `Console.ReadLine`. How many times does it occur?

Comment: @ClickRick `Console.ReadLine` occurs twice, once at the top of the While loop and once at the bottom.

Comment: So now explain why you're having to enter each guess twice.

Comment: @ClickRick I've removed the one at the bottom and the code works fine now, thanks

Comment: Don't change the question so much that the meaning of it is changed. That will make the existing answers very confusing. If you want to supply your final, updated code you should post that as an answer. If you have another question, post that as a new question.

Comment: @AndersAbel thanks for the advice, i'll keep that in mind for whenever I ask anything else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to put numbers on your `ReadLine` calls while improving the formatting of the question, so let's look at the second entry in your output above. The one with `40` entered three times. The three enters corresponds to `Readline()` calls 4, 5 & 1.

Only `ReadLine()` call 1 actually gets any data, the other ones should be removed.

For the number of tries, you should add a variable that you increment for each turn in the loop

```
// --- Snip ---
int guess = 0;
int guessCount = 0;
while (guess != x)
{
  guessCount++; // Increase guessCount with one for each turn of the loop.
  guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // ReadLine 1
// --- Snip ----
```